# How to find prime numbers from CSV file in Java?

Tags: java, csv, primes

I need to create a program that reads any number of comma-separated integers from a file and processes the numbers.

It also must specify if each number is prime or not; if the number is not prime, the program displays its unique factors in DESCENDING ORDER.

I am having trouble displaying the prime numbers from a file *primeOrNot.csv*

Here is my code so far, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrimeFactors {

public static boolean checkForPrime(int number) {
    boolean isItPrime = true;
    if(number <= 1) {
        isItPrime = false;
        return isItPrime;
    } else {
        for(int i = 2; i <= number/2; i++ ) {
            if ((number % i) == 0) {
                isItPrime = false; 
                break;
            }
        }
        return isItPrime;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "/Users/benharrington/Desktop/primeOrNot.csv";
    String line = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(line);
            boolean isItPrime = checkForPrime(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: And what is the trouble?

Comment: Right now you are printing *all* numbers you read. You don't print only the prime numbers. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: It seems like you read the whole line and pass it to `parseInt`, you have to split the string  or use a `Scanner`. Also, check the comment above

Comment: It seems you're entirely missing the point of the assignment. The job is not to check if a number is a prime number. The job is to find and print the unique factors of the number. If there are no factors, then it's a prime number. So forget about the prime part, since you'll get that for free, and work on finding the factors of a given number, since that is the part that really needs to be solved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code, it is working as required:

```
public class PrimeFactors   {

public static void findFactor(int n) {
    System.out.print("Factors for the number " + n + " is : ");
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}

public static boolean checkForPrime(int number) {

    boolean isItPrime = true;

    if (number <= 1) {
        isItPrime = false;
        return isItPrime;
    } else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
            if ((number % i) == 0) {
                isItPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isItPrime;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "/Users/benharrington/Desktop/primeOrNot.csv";
    String line = "";

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split(",");

            for (String str : values) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
                boolean isItPrime = checkForPrime(i);

                if (isItPrime)
                    System.out.println(i + " is Prime");
                else
                    System.out.println(i + " is not Prime");

                if (isItPrime == false) {
                    list.add(i);

                }

            }
            for (int k : list) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                findFactor(k);

            }

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I keep receiving this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11,25,17,30,50,3"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
 at PrimeFactors.main(PrimeFactors.java:48)

Comment: now it will work, it was a file format issue. I updated the code check it again please. @bean